# Does this particular paragraph about zero point quantum field make sense?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

Zero point quantum field is a non-exited, non-uniform gradient distribution of oscillatory motions and charge densities of energy-quanta and impulse
regime, a field without quiet mass but endowed with energy and impulse, an extended system of spatial and subliminal electromagneticoscillations (called zero
point oscillations because unable to excite the field) whose activity is described
by using a coefficient of proportionality known as quantum of fundamental action (the Planck constant h, the smallest entity of divisibility of energy per time
unity), that relates the frequency (v)of oscillation of the field with its capacity to
generate interference, i.e. with its energy (e), establishing that the value of energy
(e) of a quantum oscillator is given by the product of its frequency (v) through
the constant h = 6.63 × 10−34 Joule/sec, that fixes the energy index at which the
transition from the explicatedspin-internal motion domain to the zero point
quantum field it occurs:
e = hv
The energy (capacity to generate interference within the physic dimension) of
a quantum oscillator is the quantum interface that places the oscillator in a biunivocal relationship with the relativistic domain and with the quantum and supra-quantum domain

Answer (score 3):

No.
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: what about it don't make sense, please elaborate

Comment: Nothing about it makes any sense. It looks like somebody chose some words at random from different physics textbooks and then tried to combine them together into one long run-on sentence. There is no way to modify it to make sense.

Comment: @Hihwsjai I tried reading the paragraph to see where it goes off track. In fact the first four words "Zero point quantum field" don't make sense to me. You can have zero-point *energy* in a quantum field. But there is no such thing as a zero-point quantum field. The fact that the rest of the paragraph adds more (similarly confusing) words to this starting point doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you for the response both